# Authentification manager + database

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to set up an authentication system on my spring boot application using spring boot security but I am having trouble getting it to work with my database. 
If I try to log in with the credentials of a user created in my InMemoryUserDetailsManager, my AuthenticationManager works completely (it throws an error if the credentials are wrong). 
However, if I try with the credentials of a user in my database, it doesn't work because it seems to not be logged in with my AuthenticationManager.
I'm new to spring boot and spring security, sorry if my problem is a bit stupid.
Here is my code that might help you understand my problem:

```java
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager(){
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("user1").password(passwordEncoder.encode("1234")).authorities("USER").build(),
                User.withUsername("user2").password(passwordEncoder.encode("1234")).authorities("USER").build(),
                User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("1234")).authorities("USER","ADMIN").build()
        );
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf ->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                                auth.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
```

```java
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Map<String,String> Login(@RequestBody User user){

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword())
        );
```

My database is correctly configured and contains a user

Comment: can you point out any error trace that you get or what you expect when you hit the login endpoint? Once you set up your DaoAuthenticationProvider with userdetail service and password encoder, it should automatically auth your endpoint through httpsecurity set up. The above login endpoint is a bit out of place as the authentication manager works at levels higher the eventual rest end point. See this guide for better explanation - https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/spring-security-authentication-providers/

Comment: Oh man, I found my issue, the problem was that I needed to create a Bean userService and work with the email. I add 2 issues in fact but solved them.
Ur link helped me alot, thanks and have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone that could be in the same situation as me, u must add this in your code :

```java
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return  email->userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }
```

Moreover, u must change your authenticationManager like this :

```java
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }
```